# I want to display a message that this app can not be viewed in this small device

Tags: javascript

I want to display a message that this app can not be viewed in this small device 
for eg (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)

Answer (score 0):

give it the id noshowmessage and this css

```
@media (min-width:480px){
    #noshowmessage{
        display:none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can do with media query , if you want to do in javascript/jquery try using this ,

```
if(window.matchMedia("(max-width : 480px)").matches) {
}
```